# Spring Boot - Camel - Maven: How to add my own parent Dependency along with Spring Boot Dependency?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, apache-camel

Following is parent dependency

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.rabu.practor</groupId>
    <artifactId>integrator</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

I want to make project as spring boot project without touching parent inclusion and i am not allowed to change parent.

Following are versions in use

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Following are camel dependency in current project:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-infinispan</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cdi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Could anyone please help how to achieve it in spring boot

Comment: you can make spring boot as parent of 'your parent' project

Comment: @Shailesh: And what to do with parent dependency?

Comment: use the dependencies in child project or module where you need them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get benefit of spring-boot dependency management by adding the `spring-boot-dependencies` artifact with `scope=import`.

```
<dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Without the parent POM, you no longer will benefit from plugin management. You need to add the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` explicitly.

To use a different version for a certain dependency than the one managed by Boot, you need to declare it in the `dependencyManagement` section, before `spring-boot-dependencies` is declared.

Comment: Thanks. So i need to keep parent pom intact and copy paste the above <dependenciesmanagement> in it and then add camel starter dependency in <dependency> tag outside Dependency Management. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. If required to override a particular version, add it to dependency Management